# Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.ts(2345)

Tags: jquery, reactjs, typescript

I am getting the following error:

> Argument of type 'FunctionComponent> & { WrappedComponent: ComponentType<{ intl: IntlShape; } & ISortContainerProps>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WrappedComponent>>'.
>     Type 'FunctionComponent> & { WrappedComponent: ComponentType<{ intl: IntlShape; } & ISortContainerProps>; }' is not assignable to type 'WrappedComponentFactory>>'.
>       Type 'ReactElement ReactElement Component)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component)> | null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
>         Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.ts(2345)

I am trying to wrap my list with `SortableContainer` from `react-sortable-hoc` and export it. My component is:

```
class SortContainer extends React.Component<{ intl: IntlShape } & ISortContainerProps, {}> {

  public render() {

    ...

    return (
      <Row className={style.sortableList}>
        <List striped>
          <List.Header
            name={formatMessage(messages.detailsType)}
            width={2}
          />
          ...
          {
            items &&
            !!items.length &&
            items.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={`detailsRowId__${index}`}>
                ...
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            })
          }
        </List>
      </Row>
    );
  }
}

export default
  SortableContainer(
    injectIntl(
      observer(SortContainer)
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not export your list without using HOC SortableContainer and then wrap it where it is used like in [this example](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/blob/master/examples/collections.js)

```
export default injectIntl(observer(SortContainer)));
```

Then in your caller component:

```
const SortableList = SortableContainer<any>(({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>);
```

and call it like this:

```
<SortableList onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd}>
    <SortContainer
        ...
    />
</SortableList>
```